Children in a field trapped under a transparent dome who interact with a strange machine inside their car
I watched this movie on Hulu somewhere around 2019-2022. It's European, about Western or Northern, I believe. Possibly Danish or Dutch. I believe it was entered into a film festival as well.
I'm not sure, but I think it's about the world ending. I remember it as being cerebral with a lot of dialogue, shot pretty much in that one location in a field. I think the machine in the car was supposed to help them somehow.
The dome was a force-field, it wasn't an actual dome made out of metal or what have you. The movie itself was science fiction. I didn't remember it having much horror. Maybe a bit of suspense and a little scariness. As for the kids, I think they were about pre-teen to teenage. I'm not quite sure how they came upon the car, or if it was already there. And I don't think there was any mention of parents.
Lastly, I think what made it memorable to me was that it was such a small movie. One location, less than four protagonists, I believe. Even though I don't quite remember the message or if there were aliens in it, I believe it was maybe a social commentary of sorts. It was quite experimental. Its surrealness made it memorable.

Not a dupe, but if you like films about kids and bubbles; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150921/identify-this-80s-movie-about-a-force-field-shaped-like-a-bubble

This is Aura (2014).
Four teens are trapped in a bubble in a field.




Oh, hey, you did it! How did you find this? I'm a bit embarrassed by how off I was on certain details, but yes, this is it. Thank you so very much c:

@AlexWang - Your edit was most helpful. Once I knew that it was an ensemble cast, I just started searching for numbers ("Four teens"" and "in a field") got me there
